# How to reduce the number of MySQL requests for non-sensitive data?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I own a multi-user website : some key values are displayed for everybody (number of people registered...), some others are tied to a particular user (number of messages posted...).

So far, everytime someone goes on the index.php page, the div containing the number of users is updated by a MySQL request. Same thing for a registered user : everytime he clicks on his profile, I perform a request to retrieve the number of messages he posted.

Assuming the data to be retrieved is non-sensitive, how can I reduce the number of requests ?

For instance :
For the users, I plan to store some values using cookies as soon as they request their profile page. If they write a new message, then I'll increment the number of messages posted in the DB, and I'll increment the value in their cookie. Otherwise, everytime they connect to their profile page, I"ll display the value in the cookies. Is it less time-consuming than performing a COUNT() with MySQL ?

For the website global stats, what is the best way to proceed ?

Thanks, and sorry for the way i asked the question, I'm not a native english speaker

Comment: What about using cache ? like redis or memcached ?

Comment: I thought about caching but I'm not sure redis or memcached are available, because I own a shared hosting, I don't have a dedicated server. But thanks I'll give it a look

Comment: You could either store the value in a session variable, and have a dirty flag to help decide whether to refresh that value from the database, or wrap the function retreiving the value from the database in another, storing the value for the user in a hashmap.

Comment: Yes maybe sessions are the easiest way to achieve my goal. But the number of registered people is a value to be shared by everybody, so is the session variable a good solution (there will be as many session vars as connected users, but all sharing the same value) ?